# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when patching value

Tags: angular

I am trying to set a value on my form. What I did is I patched it on my field form but its having an error:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

on these lines:

```
coursemodule_course_id: this.coursemodules.coursemodule_course_id.id
```

How to resolve these? Below is my full code:

```js
@Input() coursemodules: any = []

moduleForm = new FormGroup({
    class_id: new FormControl(''),
    coursemodule_title: new FormControl(''),
    coursemodule_course_id: new FormControl('')
});

constructor(
    private coursemoduleService: CoursemoduleapiService
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.moduleForm.patchValue({
        coursemodule_course_id: this.coursemodules.coursemodule_course_id.id
    })
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.moduleForm.patchValue({
        coursemodule_course_id: this.coursemodules.coursemodule_course_id.id
    })
}

saveModuleForm() {
    console.log(this.moduleForm.value);
    this.coursemoduleService.createCourseModules(
        this.moduleForm.get('class_id').value, 
        this.moduleForm.get('coursemodule_title').value,
        this.moduleForm.get('coursemodule_course_id').value).subscribe(
        result => console.log(result),
        error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

Comment: `this.coursemodules` is list [ ] as per your code, you should use specific index to access `coursemodule_course_id` like this `this.coursemodules[index].coursemodule_course_id.id;` or you can do console log to get mode idea. `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.coursemodules));`

Comment: `this.coursemodules` is empty

Comment: this.coursemodules is coming from input. So make sure you are passing it from parent. Also it should be an object instead of an array.